# Uninstall MySQL completely from Ubuntu

Tags: mysql

I have trouble uninstalling MySQL from Ubuntu. I used the following commands, it doesn't seem to help as I still find the MySQL folder in `/etc` directory

1. aptitude remove mysql-client
2. aptitude remove mysql-server
3. aptitude remove mysql-common

Please suggest a good way to uninstall it completely and any command to check if the uninstallation was successful. Thank you!

Comment: http://stuffthatspins.com/2011/01/08/ubuntu-10-x-completely-remove-and-clean-mysql-installation/

Answer (score 10):

`sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-client mysql-server`

Comment: If something is wrong in precedent upgrade, you have to remove the name packages and the list of historical actions in /var/dpkg/status,